# Install Ubuntu in dualboot on drive “D” while keeping data on “D” (accessible from Ubuntu and Windows)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-8

I have had Ubuntu on my laptop for 3 years now, but this laptop was delivered with Ubuntu, so I am new to Ubuntu installation.

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 on the desktop computer at home, which has Windows 8, and 2 physical drives, with “C:” on one, and “D:” on the other one. The computer has a *Legacy BIOS*, not UEFI booting system.

There is some data on D: (100Gb out of 290), I would like to keep it.

**What I would like ideally is:**

Install Ubuntu on the same disk as D: , while leaving the original data (117 Gb out of 298). Ubuntu should be in dualboot with Windows.

I would like that *the DATA partition on D is accessible by both Ubuntu and Windows*, but I don't know if that is possible, or possible without reformating the whole D: anyway.

**I have several questions about the procedure to follow:**

1. I feel like I can just choose the default installation: "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" ?
   (according to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656058/installing-ubuntu-on-a-second-hard-drive-with-data-on-it))
2. But before that, do I need to go into the BIOS and set D as the booting drive ?
3. Should I choose the customed installation ("Something else") ?

I am sorry if it has already been asked but I don't want to break everything, although I have done all the back-ups.

**The computer specifications:**

- Packard Bell BV IMEDIA X9492
- Legacy BIOS
- Windows 8.1 (came with Vista) 32 bits
- Processor x64 Intel Core 2 Quad CPU 2.40 GHz
- RAM 3 Go (it says 2.75 usable, I don't know why)
- Nvidia GeForce 7050 / NVIDIA nForce 610i
- Disk 1:

  - Partition C: NTFS 286,09 Go (free 159 Go)
  - Recovery partition: 12 Go
- Disk 2:

  - Partition D: NTFS 298,09 Go (free 181 Go)

Comment: Pilot6 answer to the question you linked to covers all your questions.

Comment: You are right. I successfully installed Xubuntu on the second disk (named `sdb`) using the first option ("install alongside windows"). Strangely though, during the installation, the menu "select disk" proposed only one disk (`sdb`), the one I wanted, so it was ok but I wonder why `sda` wasn't shown.

Comment: My best guess with no information is likely a lack of space on `sda`